# php - How do i insert HTML table data into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML table with text and radio inputs that i want to insert each row into my MySQL table with PHP

MySQL table looks like this:

```
================================
|     Name      | Status | Ext |
================================
```

HTML table

```
===============================================================
|     Name      | Present | Excused | Unexcused |     Ext     | 
===============================================================
|  text input1  |    o    |    o    |     o     |  textarea   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  text input2  |    o    |    o    |     o     |  textarea   |
and so on...
*o's are radios
```

it gets values from a MySQL query loop and i want it to be
only one of the radios can be clicked and it sends the clicked one into the Status column

Code

```
 <form method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Present</th>
            <th>Excused</th>
            <th>Unexcused</th>
            <th>Ext</th>
        </tr>
        <?php         
        echo "<tr>";
        $query = "select * from TbCard";
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo"<td><input id='name' type='text' value='" . $data['Name'] . "' readonly style='border:none;width:350px'></input></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='radio'></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='radio'></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='radio'></td>";
                echo"<td><textarea></textarea></td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        ?>
    </table>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
</form>
```

EDIT: The table is in a form tag and has the action to another .php
and i want a submit button to insert it

Comment: so you want to insert this all data in 1 column in your mysql table?

Comment: no, the text input inserts into the 'Name' column, the selected radio out of the 3 radios inserts into the 'Status' column, the textarea inserts into the 'Ext' column and all of them results in one row so it inserts multiple rows

Comment: You want to use a submit button? Is the submit button separate from the form?

Comment: @Swellar no, the submit button is in the form tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the table is dynamically filled, you need to use an array as the name attribute

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Present</th>
            <th>Excused</th>
            <th>Unexcused</th>
            <th>Ext</th>
        </tr>
        <?php         
        $query = "select * from TbCard";
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $count = 0;
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="tableRow[<?php echo $count; ?>]['dataName']" id='name' type='text' value="<?php echo $data['Name'];?>" readonly style='border:none;width:350px'></input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="tableRow[<?php echo $count; ?>]['status']" type="radio" value="Present"> Present
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="tableRow[<?php echo $count; ?>]['status']" type="radio" value="Excused"> Excused
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="tableRow[<?php echo $count; ?>]['status']" type="radio" value="Unexcused"> Unexcused
                </td>
                </tr>;
        <?php
             $count++;
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

The `php` would be something like this, assuming that the data has values in it

```
$tableRow = $_POST['tableRow'];
foreach($tableRow as $row){
    echo $row['dataName'].' '.$row['status'].'<br/>';
}
```

That should show the values you chosen per row in the table, I don't use `mysqli` so I will not provide the the functions to insert it into the database, but the important thing is you now have the data needed

To see the content of the array, use `print_r($tableRow)`

***NOTE:*** I removed the `echo` part in the table, I might have missed some quotes or some typos, just comment for clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to your radio button. However name should be unique for each table row, so you might end up with auto generated name. Something like this:

```
...
$index = 0;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo"<td><input id='name' name='name_$index' type='text' value='" . $data['Name'] . "' readonly style='border:none;width:350px'></input></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='radio' name='status_$index'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='radio' name='status_$index'></td>";
    echo"<td><input type='radio' name='status_$index'></td>";
    echo"<td><textarea name='Ext_$index'></textarea></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    $index++;
}
...
```

As a matter of fact, you need to add a unique name to each of the fields, including text and textarea to make sure you insert values of each row separately.

Now to retrieve values for saving in the db, you could do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if(strpos($key, 'name_') === 0 )
    {
        $criteria = explode("_", $key);
        $index = $criteria[2];
        //now you can get the rest of the fields
        $status = $_POST["status_$index"];
        $name = $_POST["name_$index"];
        $ext = $_POST["Ext_$index"];
        //assuming you have a SaveFunction:
        SaveFunction($name, $status, $ext);
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do you insert the data into the database?

Comment: @Swellar from another table i probably didn't choose the best thing to show the text so i just went to put the text into a readonly input text

Answer (score 0):

first of all your are not sending your data properly

```
            echo"<td><input id='name' type='text' value='" . $data['Name'] . "' readonly style='border:none;width:350px'></input></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='radio' name='status' value='Present' ".isset($data['Status']) && $data['Status']=='Present'? checked='checked':null."></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='radio' name='Status' value='Excused' ".isset($data['Status']) && $data['Status']=='Excused'? checked='checked':null."></td>";
            echo"<td><input type='radio' name='Status' value='Unexcused' ".isset($data['Status']) && $data['Status']=='Unexcused'? checked='checked':null."></td>";
            echo"<td><textarea name='Ext'></textarea></td>";
```

This is only the part for viewing and insertion properly. let me know if you need help in insert.php side

Comment: yeah sure how do you make the insert.php?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, can you please update your question showing your efforts in insert.php?

Comment: nevermind, i already found the answer from another guy, thanks though!